# D3 - control the number of ticks on axis

Tags: d3.js

I have a simple demo here https://stackblitz.com/edit/d3-workshop-axis-n8kia7

Its just a simple graph showing the axis.

I know I can control the number of axis ticks with `ticks(5)` but how can I use it in this code

Comment: Sorry I'm sure I tried that but it didn't work. I thought my stackblitz had that on it commented out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to define the ticks when you define the scale. 
For example in your code

```
const x_axis = d3.axisBottom()
                 .scale(x);
```

you have to add .ticks(5) after .scale(x). Something like this

```
    const x_axis = d3.axisBottom()
                     .scale(x)
                     .ticks(5);
```

and at last '.ticks()' doesn't force the number of ticks, it just gives an approximation for d3. For more control on ticks, you can refer [this link](https://github.com/d3/d3-array/blob/v1.2.4/README.md#ticks)

Answer (score -2):

Body must be at least 30 characters; you entered 16.

`x_axis.ticks(5);`

Comment: Instead of copying the system "Body must be at least 30 characters; you entered 16." message you could put an explanation of your answer in. As it is, it just looks like you typed some code, couldn't submit it as an answer, then copied whatever text was available to allow posting.